# rpyc connection closed by peer

Tags: python, eoferror, rpyc

I'm following rpyc tutorials on [this page](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/tut5.html#tut5) but get EOFError when run this code

```
bgsrv = rpyc.BgServingThread(conn) #creates a bg thread to process incoming events
```

I've searched a lot but didn't find a way to fix this issue.
The server and client run in same machine. I'm running the script on macbook pro. 
Need help in fixing this error.

You can find the source code of stream.py [here](https://github.com/tomerfiliba/rpyc/blob/master/rpyc/core/stream.py).

Here is the traceback:

```
Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpyc-3.3.0-py2.7.egg/rpyc/utils/helpers.py", line 204, in _bg_server
    self._conn.serve(self.SERVE_INTERVAL)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpyc-3.3.0-py2.7.egg/rpyc/core/protocol.py", line 387, in serve
    data = self._recv(timeout, wait_for_lock = True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpyc-3.3.0-py2.7.egg/rpyc/core/protocol.py", line 345, in _recv
    data = self._channel.recv()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpyc-3.3.0-py2.7.egg/rpyc/core/channel.py", line 50, in recv
    header = self.stream.read(self.FRAME_HEADER.size)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpyc-3.3.0-py2.7.egg/rpyc/core/stream.py", line 195, in read
    raise EOFError("connection closed by peer")
EOFError: connection closed by peer
```